# Direct standardization (epidemiology)

Tags: standard-error, standardization, epidemiology

[image]

I am unsure how to prove the statement in question (c).

For the unexposed group, I did the standardizations this way;

```
for the age group 40-49:  
rate = (17/3) / (607.9/1000) = 9.321
for the age group 50-59: 
rate = (17/3) / (1272.1/1000) = 4.454
for the age group 60 - 69: 
rate = (17/3) / (888.9 / 1000) = 6.374
```

I am stuck and unsure how to continue. This is because, even if I added up the person-years for each age group in the unexposed group, the total person-years and total number of cases are constant. 
 Appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Try to understand what is standardized rate.What you did is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is figuring out the formula for the variance of a directly standardised rate, which is

$$\sum_i{w_i^2 (c_i/p_i^2)}$$

where $w$ is the proportion of the standardised population in stratum $i$, $c$ is the number of cases in the stratum, and $p$ is the person-time of observation.